# C++ Convert string logical expression to conditional expression

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20

I have a logical expression in string and need to evaluate. Is there a way in C++ do it?

```
std::string exp = "(1||0)&&(1&&1)&&(1||0&&0)";
```

Eg:

```
if ((1 || 0) && (1 && 1) && (1 || 0 && 0))
    {
        std::cout << "true\n";
    }
```

Comment: If you are looking for something like an `eval`-function that executes code from a string, then the answer is no. Such thing does not and will not exist in C++. Your solution needs to parse the string and execute code based on the evaluation of it.

Comment: What is the *original* problem? Where does this string come from? Why do you need to evaluate it? Does it have to be evaluated at compile-time, or at run-time?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude This need to evaluated at runtime

Comment: Get yourself a book on compilers. The Dragon Book by Abo et al is a classic.

Comment: s/Abo/Aho/ sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no easy built-in way in C++ to evaluate logic expressions like that. If you want to evaluate such an expression in runtime, you need to parse a string into some intermediate representation first (e.g. an expression tree) by writing a parser and write an evaluator that will flatten that tree into a single value.

Then, assuming

```
struct ExprTree { ... };
ExprTree parse(std::string const& input);
bool eval(ExprTree const& expr);
```

you can get the result of such a string expression with

```
std::string exp = "(1||0)&&(1&&1)&&(1||0&&0)";
if (eval(parse(exp)) {
    // ... 
}
```